# Syntax error on 'mod' Haskell

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I am following a haskell tutorial: http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/lectures/01-intro.html

I am testing functions in ghci, i got to this part:

```
hailstone :: Integer -> Integer
hailstone n
  | n `mod` 2 == 0 = n `div` 2
  | otherwise      = 3*n + 1
```

I have that function in a .hs file, i fire up ghci in the same directory and go :l hailstone.hs

the output is

```
Syntax error on 'mod'
    Perhaps you intended to use TemplateHaskell
    In the Template Haskell quotation 'mod'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

did some googling and tried to load this 'templatehaskell' and just ended up with a different set of errors (http://brandon.si/code/working-with-template-haskell-in-ghci/)

Comment: ideone.com is happy with this: http://ideone.com/pe3g9C

Comment: Typically that happens when `mod` is written as a top-level form. Is the definition of hailstone the only thing in the file?

Comment: Are you by any chance typing " ' " ('mod') as opposed to " ` " (\`mod \`) ? The latter is correct while the former is not; the backtick is not the same as the single quote.

Comment: @user2407038

well... this is embarrassing...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [user2407038](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2407038/user2407038) correctly suggested in the comments, the problem was that I was using apostrophes (`'`) as opposed to backticks (`` ` ``), the backtick is not the same as the single quote which I should have been using.

Comment: @David Nono, this _is_ the answer to this question.