# Haskell Parse error in pattern

Tags: haskell

```
isValid :: Position -> Bool
isValid Position(x _) = x
isValid Position(_ y) = y
    | x 'elem' ['a'..'h'] && y 'elem' [1..8] = True
    | otherwise = False
```

I keep getting this error `error: Parse error in pattern: x`
I am trying to write a function that tells me whether a given poisition is valid or not. Where `x` is `['a'..'h']` and `y` is `[1..8]`

Comment: What is the definition of the `Position` type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
    | x 'elem' ['a'..'h'] && y 'elem' [1..8] = True
```

`x` is unbound. It doesn't appear at all in

```
isValid Position(_ y) = y
```

in particular. Also, you probably meant to use `` `elem` ``, and not `'elem'`.

> I am trying to write a function that tells me whether a given poisition is valid or not. Where x is ['a'..'h'] and y is [1..8]

You didn't write the definition of `Position`, but it seems like this would be something like

```
data Position = Position Int Int                                                                                                                                     

isValid :: Position -> Bool
isValid (Position x y) = x `elem` ['a'..'h'] && y `elem` [1..8]
```

(which builds for me).

Comment: @Dave You also have another error, in using `'elem'` instead of `\`elem\``, and another one besides that. See updated answer.

Comment: @Dave As you seem new to the site (at least by your rep), note that you can accept a single answer, but, independently upvote whatever answers helped you. JonPurdy seems to have answered your question too correctly, so you might want to upvote it as thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As explained here: [Syntax error on 'mod' Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543686/syntax-error-on-mod-haskell/24544188#24544188)

The syntax for using a named function as an infix operator uses backticks (grave accents, U+0060), not apostrophes:

```
    | x `elem` ['a'..'h'] && y `elem` [1..8] = True
        ------                 ------
    | otherwise = False
```

In addition, `Position(x _)` and `Position(_ y)` are not valid patterns—you probably intended to use `(Position x _)` and `(Position x y)`. Note the `x`, since `x` is not in scope in the equation you wrote for `(Position _ y)`.

`(Position x _)` will match all positions, so I suspect you intended:

```
isValid :: Position -> Bool
isValid (Position x y)
    | x `elem` ['a'..'h'] && y `elem` [1..8] = True
    | otherwise = False
```

Or more simply:

```
isValid :: Position -> Bool
isValid (Position x y) = x `elem` ['a'..'h'] && y `elem` [1..8]
```

Answer (score 3):

> I keep getting this error error: Parse error in pattern: `x` I am trying to write a function that tells me whether a given position is valid or not. Where `x` is `['a'..'h']` and `y` is `[1..8]`.

The other answers already discussed what is wrong: you used a guard in the clause where there is no bounded `x`:

```
isValid Position(_ y) = y
```

and furthermore you use quotes instead of backticks with the `elem` function:

```
x 'elem' ['a'..'h']
```

So a rigorous fix would be:

```
isValid :: Position -> Bool
isValid (Position x y)
    | x `elem` ['a'..'h'] && y `elem` [1..8] = True
    | otherwise = False
```

Since we actually return the result of the guard, we do not need to use guards and can collapse the guards into one expression:

```
isValid :: Position -> Bool
isValid (Position x y) = x `elem` ['a'..'h'] && y `elem` [1..8]
```

Nevertheless since we here work with *ranges* and the second range are integers, we do not have to use `elem` on a range, we can use:

```
isValid :: Position -> Bool
isValid (Position x y) = 'a' <= x && x <= 'h' && 1 <= y && y <= 8
```

For such small ranges, there will probably not be that much impact on performance, but `elem` works in *O(n)* worst case, whereas the two bounds checks work in *O(1)*.